# Hide show eye icon inside password field angular 6

Tags: angular

The function is working fine but i'm doing it with a checkbox till now
I just need help with the eye icon inside the password input field
without bootstrap or font-awesome if possible
and thanks

```
      myFunction() {
  let x : any = document.getElementById("inputPassword");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}

<input [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" id="inputPassword"  name="password"
                     placeholder="{{'Password' | translate}}"  required>
                     <input type = "checkbox" (click)="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do as the official were documented:

Instead of setting type in the component use dynamic value for the type attribute.

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
```

TS Code:

```
hide : boolean = true;

myFunction() {
  this.hide = !this.hide;
}
```

[`Working_Demo_with_eye_icon`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nirsan)

Comment: Thaaanks it is working. But can you help me how to put it inside the input field !!!

Comment: do you use ` <mat-form-field>`?

Comment: no I can't use mat-form(field now because i'm using specific cs classes.

Comment: I thnik it's working while inspecting but my input is hiding it , i will try fixing it with CSS. Thans very much !!!

Comment: I tried your solution, but I don't understand, how you set `mat-icon` icon @PrashantPimpale

Comment: @EugeneSukh check the stackblitz demo its there inside span tag

Comment: I tried, but only I see, that's text  `visibility_off` or `visibility` @PrashantPimpale

Comment: @EugeneSukh then i think you missed to refer google icon link, from that demo check index.html you will see google icon link..which you need to include

Comment: Yup. Thanks @PrashantPimpale

Answer (score 2):

> Here is [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-and-hide-password-f2etmy?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
<ion-content padding>

  <form>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-list-header>
       type Password
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input
          [type]="ismyTextFieldType ? 'text' : 'password'"
          placeholder="Enter your password"
        >
        </ion-input>
        <button
          (click)="togglemyPasswordFieldType()"
          ion-button
          item-right
        >
          <ion-icon
            [name]="ismyTextFieldType ? 'eye-off' : 'eye'"
          >
          </ion-icon>
        </button>  
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>

</ion-content>
```

in .ts file

```
 ismyTextFieldType: boolean;

  togglemyPasswordFieldType(){
    this.isTextFieldType = !this.isTextFieldType;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

html only solution:

```html
<mat-form-field>
 <input type="password" matInput #password />
 <mat-icon
  style="cursor: pointer"
  matSuffix
  (mousedown)="password.type = 'text'"
  (mouseup)="password.type = 'password'"
  [inline]="true">
   {{ password.type == "password" ? "visibility_off" : "visibility" }}
  </mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```